# finite group of square-free order $n$ has subgroup of order $d$ where $d\mid n$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group (possibly not commutative) and $d$ be an arbitrary number which divides $|G|$. If $G$ is square-free, i.e. $\forall n\colon n^2$ doesn't divide $   |G|$, can we say that $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$?

My first attempt was to use the Sylow's theorem. I denoted $d= p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$ and took the Sylow $p_i$-subgroup $H_i$. However, I couldn't say that $H_1 H_2\cdots H_n$ is even a subgroup, since they are in general not normal subgroups.

I also tried to say that $G$ is nilpotent (so $G$ is the direct sum of $H_i$). I guess that's not true...

Comment: Yes, this is true, but it is not quite trivial to see. The crucial connection is that groups of squarefree order are supersolvable, and supersolvable groups satisfy the converse of Lagrange.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll check it.